# Vuforia Unity problem on android can see phone menu on the background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I created project on Unity with Vuforia, and catch some problem. After I build app for android, when i start it i can see phone menu on the background. If anyone could tell me where i can dig, if this is problem on camera component or anything? This how it looks like

[image: This how it looks like]